# How to load XML from "upload form" and parse to table html

Tags: php, xml

I wanted to point out first. That I already spent the whole 5 days on this before writing the question, and tried many solutions and unfortunately I think I've exhausted my options. I'm still learning so please be understanding and help me.

I created upload form:

```
            <div class="row" id="upload_area">
              <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-md-6" align="right">Select File</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="file" name="file" id="xml_file" />
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
                </div>
              </form>
              
            </div>
```

Here I have upload.php

```
<?php

//upload.php

session_start();

$error = '';

$html = '';

if($_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
{
 $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);

 $extension = end($file_array);

 if($extension == 'xml')
 {
  $file_data = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

  $file_header = simplexml_load_file($file_data);

  $html .= '<table class="table table-bordered"><tr>';

  for($count = 0; $count < count($file_header); $count++)
  {
   $html .= '
   <th>
    <select name="set_column_data" class="form-control set_column_data" data-column_number="'.$count.'">
     <option value="">Set Count Data</option>
     <option value="sku">sku</option>
     <option value="category_id">category_id</option>
     <option value="price">price</option>
     <option value="discount_rate">discount_rate</option>
     <option value="vat_rate">vat_rate</option>
     <option value="stock">stock</option>
     <option value="external_link">external_link</option>
    </select>
   </th>
   ';
  }

  $html .= '</tr>';

  $limit = 0;

  while(($row = simplexml_load_file($file_data)) !== FALSE)
  {
   $limit++;

   if($limit < 6)
   {
    $html .= '<tr>';

    for($count = 0; $count < count($row); $count++)
    {
     $html .= '<td>'.$row[$count].'</td>';
    }

    $html .= '</tr>';
   }

   $temp_data[] = $row;
  }

  $_SESSION['file_data'] = $temp_data;

  $html .= '
  </table>
  <br />
  <div align="right">
   <button type="button" name="import" id="import" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Import</button>
  </div>
  <br />
  ';
 }
 else
 {
  $error = 'Only <b>.xml</b> file allowed';
 }
}
else
{
 $error = 'Please Select XML File';
}

$output = array(
 'error'  => $error,
 'output' => $html
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

But something went wrong. Can anyone help me correct this code to read this XML file from input and convert to HTML table?

For CSV file with fopen  this working correct. I try also add option for XML files. For this I use simplexml_load_file. But when I upload in form, then not working and something went wrong in script code.

Only for information for above to reprocude issue, this is my script for post form:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
      $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(event){
    
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url:"upload.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:new FormData(this),
          dataType:'json',
          contentType:false,
          cache:false,
          processData:false,
          success:function(data)
          {
            if(data.error != '')
            {
              $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.error+'</div>');
            }
            else
            {
              $('#process_area').html(data.output);
              $('#upload_area').css('display', 'none');
            }
          }
        });
    
      });
    
    });
    </script>
```

update:

everytime my form return error: when I upload .xml then still return "only .xml file allowed"

[issue with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFBvv.png)

For better check here is possible to check issue  script with XML load: http://import2.webincloud.pl/

and for campare, here is the same way working script but in CSV load https://import.webincloud.pl/ and for .CSV working correct.

Comment: Your upload script is always returning an error. Do you have any errors in the web server log?

Comment: I have only error when I upload .xml " Only .xml file allowed"

Comment: https://prnt.sc/24MN6XD9Lql_

Comment: Whats the value of $file_array?

Comment: I try load sample .xml file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<products>
  <product>
    <child1>data1</child1>
    <child2>A1343358848646</child2>
   </product>
  </products>

Comment: @Jason K for testing you can load here sample any csv file then you can see working: http://import.webincloud.pl/  but I cant do it for xml

Comment: This line(if($extension == 'xml')) deter mends the error message. Are you sure you know what is in there, Case matters Xml != xml

Comment: @JasonK currently I removed this line and now I can load file: but I not see content from .xml file in table https://prnt.sc/lgTkpawYBACH

Comment: Only mapping fields without .xml content https://prnt.sc/rvq_el0lSZG7

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems like you've tried to make some amendments to some code that works with CSV files. This line looks a lot like what you would do if you were reading a CSV file row by row using fgetcsv():

`while(($row = simplexml_load_file($file_data)) !== FALSE)`

This logic won't work when using simplexml_load_file, because this function parses the whole XML file, it doesn't go row by row.

What the above line is actually doing in your code when you run it using simplexml_load_file() is creates an infinite loop because the while clause never ends, $row always !== (i.e. does not equal) FALSE, only stopping when you exhaust the memory PHP is allowed to use. If you examine your php_errors.log you will notice the following error:

`simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in upload.php on line 21`

This is caused because $file_data is set on line 19 to a resource from fopen():

`$file_data = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');`

simplexml_load_file wants a path to an xml file, not for the file to already be loaded as a resource in your code. So you should pass `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` directly, not using fopen().

My recommendation is to try this at the top of your code, to see how simplexml_load_file loads the xml data and then stop running:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
print_r($xml, true);
die();
```

Once you review the output of this code, you'll be able to build a structure to pull the headers and then iterate through the data and format it into a table.

Here's some code you can use, but without knowing the exact syntax of your xml file some modification will be necessary and I therefore cannot give you a fully working answer. My code is based on uploading through your form page a sample XML file books.xml found on a [Microsoft support website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)):

```
// Get the XML file loaded in to a variable
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);                      
}

// Get the keys from the resulting object to give you a list of headings for your table
// If your $xml file returns a mutli-dimensional / nested array, use the syntax $xml->products or whatever fits your data
$headings = array_keys(get_object_vars($xml->book));
error_log(print_r($headings, true));
/* Output of print_r($headings, true); using the books.xml example:
[24-Nov-2022 00:30:28 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => @attributes
    [1] => author
    [2] => title
    [3] => genre
    [4] => price
    [5] => publish_date
    [6] => description
)
*/
// Iterate through the XML items to create rows for your table
foreach ($xml->book as $book) {
  error_log(print_r($book, true));
}
/* Output of print_r($book, true); using the books.xml example:
[24-Nov-2022 00:41:18 UTC] SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => bk112
        )

    [author] => Galos, Mike
    [title] => Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide
    [genre] => Computer
    [price] => 49.95
    [publish_date] => 2001-04-16
    [description] => Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.
)
.... and so on
*/
// Access values like so:
foreach ($xml->book as $book) {
  error_log("Author: " . $book->author);
  error_log("Title: " . $book->title);
  error_log("Genre: " . $book->genre);
  // ... and so on
}
```